# FreeCAD: Scene doesn't look 3D

Tags: freecad

I finished a 3D object for 4 wheels, but something seems wrong with the final scene to me:

The nearer wheels (#1 and #2) appear smaller than the far one (#3 and #4), and the distance between wheel #3 an #4 seems longer than between (1) and (2), like you can see in this picture:

[image: 4 wheels]

I want to achieve the scene like this:

[image: Example of a wanted render]

How to do that in FreeCAD?

Comment: Welcome to SE.3DP! Your question is not specifically on-topic for 3D Printing Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: You might want to consult the manual at https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Getting_started

Answer (score 5):

FreeCAD, like many other 3D programs (including blender) does use Isometric/Orthographic display as the default displaying option as it allows to see on one view if some lengths or angles are "equal".

In many cases, a perspective view can be toggled on to allow visualization in a room, especially for architectural one.

In the case of FreeCAD with all its options, this option gets swamped out of the user's field of view sometimes, and the documentation is not that easy to navigate without a proper keyword, making the right thing slightly hidden in the documentation. But once you know it, it should be obvious:

- [`View > Perspective View`](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Std_PerspectiveCamera) toggles to perspective view.
- [`View > Orthographic View`](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Std_OrthographicCamera) toggles back to isometric.

Answer (score 2):

CAD programs uses parallel view not perspective view. 
So the length of 2 objects with the same length are displayed as 2 objects with the same length on the screen. 
This is better for constructing stuff.

Comment: while you explain WHY Isometric/Orthographic is chose, it does not explain how to switch to perspective